# How to retain a key ,product combination if key is missing in a particular week?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset like this:

```
Week   Key  Product  Value
1      AB   TRN      2.4
1      AB   LJL      4.5
1      CD   LJL      3.4
2      AB   HTF      4.5
```

Now if say in 52 weeks, I have 100 keys. I want to look for those 100 keys in every week, and if it's missing, I want to copy the all the last known data for that key to the missing week.

Comment: You will need stored procedure for this. Simple query will not do the job.

Comment: Can you at least provide example data of what you want to achieve, it's not too clear from what you've given so far

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple to do in SAS:

```
proc sort data = have;
  by key week;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by key week;
  retain last_known_value last_known_product;
  if first.key then call missing(last_known_product, last_known_value);
  if not(missing(product)) then last_known_product = product;
  if not(missing(value)) then last_known_value = value;
run;
```

Comment: I believe the poster would like every combination of key/week as well.

Comment: On the other hand, they said they wanted to carry over the last known data, which this does. It isn't particularly clear what's required prior to the first week where each key appears.

Answer (score 0):

Create some dummy data:

```
data have;
  input week 
        key $
        product $
        value
        ;
  datalines;
1      AB   TRN      2.4
1      AB   LJL      4.5
1      CD   LJL      3.4
2      AB   HTF      4.5
10     AB   TRN      5.0
;
run;
```

Get a distinct list of keys.

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table keys as select distinct key from have;
quit;
```

Create a table containing every combination of key/week.

```
data all_combinations;
  set keys;
  do week = 1 to 52;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Merge the table with the original data.

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table all_combinations2 as
  select a.key, a.week, b.product, b.value
  from all_combinations a
  left join have b on b.week = a.week and b.key = a.key
  order by key, week
  ;
quit;
```

Retain the values if they're missing.

```
data want;
  set all_combinations2;
  by key week;
  length product2 $10;
  retain product2 '' value2 .;
  product2 = ifc(cats(product) ne '',product,product2);
  value2 = ifn(value ne .,value,value2);
  drop product value;
run;
```